# how to navigate to a url using linkbutton in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, linq-to-sql

i have a gridview which stores names of software and a button field. What i want to do is that by executing a query behind "open" linkbutton and the resulting answer which is a url from database, i want to navigate to that link which is stored in the variable.
e.g: when i click open button i want to navigate to "www.google.com"

so far what i have coded is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="softwares" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" OnRowCommand="GridView2_RowCommand">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Softwares" HeaderText="Softwares" SortExpression="Softwares" />
                    <asp:ButtonField CommandName="open" Text="Open" />
                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="softwares" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:certConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT sw_name AS Softwares FROM Software"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C# code:

```
protected void GridView2_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.CommandName == "open")
            {
                using(CertDataContext context=new CertDataContext())
                {
                    int i=Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                    var open = (from a in context.Softwares where a.sw_name == GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text select a).FirstOrDefault();
                    Response.Redirect(open.tosting());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: So this is your code. What's the problem?

Comment: well Response.Redirect directs you to the page in the project but i want to redirect to a url saved in the variable open e.g www.google.com

Comment: open.tosting() looks like a typo, you should check that out. Also, FirstOrDefault() can also return null, so you should definitely check if it's not null before calling your "tosting" method.

Answer (score 0):

[HttpResponse.Redirect(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4(v=vs.110).aspx)

The parameter CAN be an absolute url. Check the example Microsoft gives in their documentation.